# I'm trying to break up a table into many based on a row value, for each change in row value A, the table breaks, and a new table begins

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, datatables

I'm pulling from a mysql query.  The goal is to break the table when the row value a changes, and create a new table.  So far, I'm able to populate the table, but i'm not able to break the table and start a new after the $row A value changes.  Any suggestions?

```
<?php 
    $previousCategory = ''; //empty variable
    $run = 0; //  counter

    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($this->query))
    {
        $run++;

        if ($previousCategory !== $row['A'] || $run == 0 ) {

        //close the table 
        if ($run != 0) {
            echo "</tbody></table>";

        } else {
                 echo ".$row['A'].";
                }

?> 
        <table id="Table">  
        <thead>
            <caption><?php echo $row['A'] ?></caption>
            <tr class="data">
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
                <th>F</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>


    <?php
            while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($this->query)) {

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['A']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['B']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['C']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['D']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['E']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['F']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
        }  // closes if.  Starts a new table.
    } // Close the while statement
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You never update `$previousCategory`. Somewhere at the bottom of the loop you should have `$previousCategory = $row['A']`. Plus, your "break" code should be WITHINT the while/fetch loop,b ecause at the point you do your break testing, you haven't actually started fetching ANYTHING from the database, and won't ever break anything.

Comment: In addition to what @MarcB said you're also making each table have the same ID and ID's must be unique in a page.